# how do I instrospect appengine's datastore models?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

in order to dynamically create a form, i have to find the property types of a model's properties at runtime.

appengine docs says that Model.properties() will return a dictionary of properties name and their class type. when i use this method in my code, only the name is returned and the classtype value is always empty.

Comment: .properties() does return a dict - but when you iterate over a dict in Python, it iterates over the keys only.

Comment: yes i know. wasn't the issue. thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`Model.kind()`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_kind)**

E.g., for a model like this:

```
class LargeTextList(db.Model):
    large_text_list = db.ListProperty(item_type=db.Text)
```

`my_model_instance.kind()` returns `LargeTextList`.

---

Edit (thanks to OP for clarification):
The property information you seek is there, but you'll need to escape to see it, e.g. in your template:

```
<p>{{ my_model_instance.properties|escape }}</p>
```

This returns:

```
{'large_text_list': <google.appengine.ext.db.ListProperty object at 0x24b1790>}
```

---

Edit2:
You can also call `properties()` on the class itself:

```
my_model = LargeTextList
```

and in the template as before (be sure to use the `escape` filter):

```
<p>{{ model.properties|escape }}</p>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. i'm not looking for the kind. but for instance in your example, that large_text_list is a ListProperty. that's what i'm looking for.

Comment: exactly what i'm doing. does it have to be on an instance? i'm only getting the keys in my properties dict.

Comment: No, doesn't need to be an instance. You can call the `kind()` method on the class itself as well. I'll add that as another example in case it helps.

Comment: @python: might help to post the bit of code that isn't working for you; including relevant template code.

Comment: Happy to help.  Enjoy your holiday weekend (if you're in the US, that is.)

Comment: Just realised that `<p>` may not be the greatest HTML element to display this information.  Ah well, gets the job done.